# Should one use self-referencing generic inheritance like Customer : Entity<Customer>

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics, inheritance

Is it advisable to use self-referencing generic inheritance?

```
public abstract class Entity<T> {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public int Version {get; set;}

    public T Clone() {
        ...
        // clone routine
        ...
        return T;
    }
}

public class Customer : Entity<Customer> {
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

How does one cast Customer to the base Entity class? What advantage does "Customer : Entity" provide? I see this kind of inheritance in examples showing NHibernate domain modeling.

Is it better to use "Customer : Entity" without the generics?

Answer (score 5):

You should use it when you need it, not just because you can. In the example above, it makes some sense to implement `Clone()`. However, as you rightly point out, it means that your entity classes won't actually have a common base class, and properties that are truly common to them won't be accessible. The correct way to handle this is to split it in generic and non-generic parts:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public int Version {get; set;}
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : Entity where T : Entity<T> {
    public T Clone() {
        ...
        // clone routine
        ...
        return T;
    }
}
```

Also, note the `where` part that I've added to declaration of `Entity<T>` - it ensures that this class can only be used as a part of this recursive pattern.

Comment: Are there any other advantage to using the generic entity? I could make the Clone method a generic method if there are no other advantages.

Comment: How would you make `Clone` generic?

Comment: I could do public T Clone<T>() { serialize/deserialize T, return T}

Comment: But then it means that if you have entity classes `Foo` and `Bar`, you can call `bar.Clone<Foo>()`. And what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Maybe I can create a static clone class on Entity. My question is if self-referencing has any other advantages besides the clone example.

Answer (score 3):

In the company i work for, the project I work on uses heavily this kind of trick. In fact, it is even promoted as a pattern in the code. Thus i can speak from experience: don't use it.

They may be cases where the self-referencing implementation is far simpler, more efficient and easier to read, but I have never encountered such a case. Heavy use of it makes code maintenance a nightmare, and in most cases can be avoided with only a normal inheritance and a casting of your method result if needed. And the performance cost of a casting into the derived class is negligible compared to the maintenance cost of your code.

So if you find the rare example where it is advisable to use self-referencing generic inheritance, go ahead and do so. But think twice beforehand, as there is probably a better way to do it.